# Unit test classes with lwuit usage

Tags: unit-testing, java-me, lwuit

I'm working under quite old app which uses LWUIT for UI.

I'm trying currently to write unit tests for MIDlet class but because there are a lot of LWUIT static methods calls it's quite hard to make it properly working even with PowerMock.

Does anyone have example of what should be completely mocked, suppressed to finally have these tests run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is way too much to mock. You can either build your own LWUITImplementation class which will allow you to do some of these things (see the ports for the various platforms). Or you can migrate the code to [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) which has its own unit testing framework and test recorder.

Comment: How could I inject own Implementation to LWUIT?

Comment: You need to implement the ImplementationFactory class to return the right class instance.

Comment: Interesting how is this "wiring" is going. I will check tomorrow. Should I call some setter to inject my implementation?

Comment: You need to replace the ImplementationFactory class with your own.

Comment: I mocked LWUITImplementation with ImplementationFactory and I'm writing tests for classes that are using LWUIT. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've actually extracted all LWUIT initialization and theme related code to a special class. I could mock it and at least test all other app functionality.

The code that is relied on LWUIT like forms and controls requires a lot of PowerMock tricks